# wpf - autosizing path

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

So I have a path which has the shape of a trapezoid:

[image]

As you can see it is really sloppy, the corners or width of the segments aren't fitting well. I have done this manually but it seems like a bad idea to me. So I want to autosize it but I don't know how.

Here is my XAML code for two of my segments(this is the same for every other segment):

```
                <StackPanel x:Name="prospects" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                <Path Data="M5,0 L70,0 75,30 0,30 z" Height="75" Stretch="Fill" Stroke="Black" Fill="Yellow" Width="400" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" >
                    <Path.RenderTransform>
                        <TransformGroup>
                            <ScaleTransform/>
                            <SkewTransform/>
                            <RotateTransform Angle="180"/>
                            <TranslateTransform/>
                        </TransformGroup>
                    </Path.RenderTransform>
                </Path>
                <TextBox x:Name="txxProspects" Height="25" Width="100" Margin="-400,0,0,0" Background="{x:Null}" />
            </StackPanel>
            <StackPanel x:Name="hotProspects" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                <Path Data="M5,0 L70,0 75,30 0,30 z" Height="75" Stretch="Fill" Width="345" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" >
                    <Path.Fill>
                        <SolidColorBrush Color="Blue" Opacity="0.5"/>
                    </Path.Fill>
                    <Path.RenderTransform>
                        <TransformGroup>
                            <ScaleTransform/>
                            <SkewTransform/>
                            <RotateTransform Angle="180"/>
                            <TranslateTransform/>
                        </TransformGroup>
                    </Path.RenderTransform>
                    </Path>
                    <TextBox x:Name="txxHotProspects" Height="25" Width="100" Margin="-340,0,0,0" Background="{x:Null}" />
            </StackPanel>
```

Can someone teach me how to do it right?

Thanks in advance!